# How to make spring security redirect

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, jsp-tags

I have two jsp pages : Page 1 and Page 2. Page1 opened by default, but to open it user need to have right role. I also have a page for access denied when the user do not have the right role to access some page. What I want to do is that when the user without the right role try to open the default page (Page1)not be redirect to the access denied page, but to Page2.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your `accessDeniedPage` like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        // your config here ...
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Page2")
    }
```

**Update**

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String method(Authentication auth) {
  if (containsRole(auth.getAuthority(), "ROLE_ADMIN")) {
    return "/PAGE1";
  } else {
    return "redirect:/PAGE2";
  }
}
```

Comment: i want both pages to exist, there`s situations when I need this access denied page

Comment: @user5783530 do you mean you are not expecting a global behaviour, but only for this case? then control it from the controller would be a better approach

Comment: yes only for this case, how can I do it from the controller

Comment: @user5783530 You can autowire `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication` in controller method, then compare with `getAuthorities()`